# Strange character in postgresql database table fields

Tags: php, html, postgresql, webforms

The following character was found in 6 of the over 30 fields in one of my postgresql tables. The character was at the end of the user-input text for each of the 6 fields. The data gets into the table by a PHP web form. It's been in use for years and this is the first time that I have seen this.

what is this character below and how did it get created:

[image: 007F Image box found in database table]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `007F`, i.e. the ["DELETE" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007f/index.htm). No idea how it got there, but this sounds more like a PHP question than a Postgres one.

Comment: I would add tags to this question that represent the technologies in-between your user and your DB. e.g. PHP, WebForms, HTML, etc.

Comment: Tags have been updated. It's nice to know at least what it is.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick says, I would imagine it is the Unicode Character 'DELETE' (U+007F). - It's one of the original `C0` ASCII Control Characters.

It got there because you are not correctly sanitizing your user data.

This may not be malicious, intended, or even known of by the user, they may just have copy and pasted the string from an application such as Microsoft Word.

Comment: I am using the following functions to sanitize the data: trim, str_replace to remove \r \n and double quotes, pg_escape_string, and htmlspecialchars. what other functions are available that would help?

Comment: How to sanitize data is another question, and dependant on your needs. Personally I would invert the process and only *keep* what I wanted, e.g. ctype_alnum, etc. Rather than stripping all the things that I can think of.